# Filter a column by more than two values (“ends with”)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I really need your guys' help because I want to filter words that end with for example `.com`,`.be`, `.nl`, `.net`, or `.org`. I know there is a option for that, but by using that option I can only filter one. See:

[image]

But I want to filter more than one. To say it simply, I want to filter multiple words that end with `.com`,`.be`, `.nl`, `.net`, or `.org`.

I want to filter this:

[image]

Thanks guys

Comment: Haven't tried, but could you do conditional formatting and then filter by color?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to separate out the domain names into their own column.  You can do this with the following formula:
`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))/LEN("."))))` (Assuming your original string value is in A1)

Further readig on the topic I linked below revealed another simpler way to do the same type of separation with `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))`

Then you can copy this down to all of your rows and use the filtering tool in Excel to select the specific domains you want.

I also suggest that you use column headers so that you aren't filtering using a data row as column headers.

To provide your answer, I used some information from the answer on this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617349/excel-last-character-string-match-in-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Using this macro will allow you to overcome the restriction of *AutoFilter*:

```
Sub FilterByHand()
    Dim N As Long, t As String
    Dim r As Range, i As Long
    Const domainList As String = "|com|net|org|be|nl|"
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To N
        Set r = Cells(i, "A")
        t = "|" & Mid(r.Value, InStrRev(r.Value, ".") + 1) & "|"
        If InStr(1, domainList, t) = 0 Then r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I golfed your code a bit. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @EngineerToast   Very interesting approach!

Comment: I have found the `InStr` approach makes it very easy to expand a list later on. However, this method will fail if the cell contains exactly one of the domain extensions. For instance, the cell value `com` will not be hidden. That's probably an edge case, though. It's possible to add a second check for the entire cell value.

Comment: Thanks guys looks still a bit complicated but I will some how figure it out. Thank you very much.